# Is there a way to combine Elasticsearch queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have two queries:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"body": "a"}},
        {"match": {"body": "b"}},
        {"match": {"body": "c"}},
        {"match_phrase": {"body": "g h i"}},
        {"match_phrase": {"body": "j k l"}}
      ],
      "should": [
        {"match": {"body": "d"}},
        {"match": {"body": "e"}},
        {"match": {"body": "f"}}
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {"match": {"body": "m"}},
        {"match": {"body": "n"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"body": "x"}},
        {"match": {"body": "y"}},
        {"match": {"body": "z"}},
        {"match_phrase": {"body": "new phrase"}},
        {"match_phrase": {"body": "second phrase"}}
      ],
      "should": [
        {"match": {"body": "T"}},
        {"match": {"body": "U"}},
        {"match": {"body": "V"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've stored these jsons in db and sometimes need to combine these together. Is there a way to combine them without recreating json from scratch?
for example something like this:

```
{'query': {'and': [query1, query2]}}
```

Comment: No. You have [search templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/search-template.html) and [multi search templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/multi-search-template.html) that come closer to what you want.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks, I think msearch is what I want. whould you please tell me how can I get to my purpose this way?

Comment: Multi search templates is different than what you need, but it's the closest thing. I'd suggest looking at both links I provided in my previous comment and see if it helps.